# How to call a method before the method of requested controller is executed : magento

Tags: events, zend-framework, magento, controller, observer-pattern

I want to call a method before the execution of every and each controller's method. I don't want to go and call the method in every method. I just want to call it from one place and it will be called before any method of any controller in magento.

And I am sure we can do this but I don't know how it can be accomplished.

Please provide your suggestions.

Hope we can resolve this or may some expert guys already resolved this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create an Observer that binds to the `controller_action_predispatch` Event.  That will fire before every controller in the Magento codebase.  There's a useful [wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) here that walks you through the process.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I gone through the wiki page and I got that I have to to create observer for all modules( like customer,checkout,review etc.). Am I going in right direction or Is there any other way?

Comment: You only need to create the Observer once.  That's the advantage of using the `controller_action_predispatch` event, it is thrown by *every* controller.  Most events are specific to customer, checkout, review, etc but `controller_action_predispatch` is global.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Yes I am trying to implement this. I think it should work. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a method called preDispatch in your controller. This method is executed before the requested controller action.

something like:

```
public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        //my code here
    }
```

Comment: That will only execute prior to your own controller's code, not every controller as the OP asked