# Page redirection in PHP instead of echo

Tags: php, magento

I am using a Magento website. If anyone searches for a product and if the product is not found, it displays 'No match found'.

I have pasted the script below:

```
<div id="partfinder_<?php echo $this->getInstanceSufix(); ?>_not_found" 
     style="display:none"><?php echo $this->__('No matches found.') ?></div>
```

I want the users to be redirected to the new page where they can fill out an enquiry form.

Comment: What is the trouble you're having?

Comment: Instead of displaying no match found, i want a new page to be opened where i will display a form so that user can fill the product details they have searched for.

Comment: @Aravind Your question is too broad, without more code and explanation it is difficult to answer it.

Comment: `if(condition) { do something } else{ do something else }`

Comment: What as in `if (dont know how to do it) { R.T.M } else { Pay a consultant }` @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Esattamente!*

Comment: @Aravind you want o redirect your page if getting no item.....if am right than go on Catalog block product list and check and redirect your page where you want

Comment: Dear @RiggsFolly, thanks for your advice. I am trying to learn, i am sure everyone would have started from this position.

Answer (score 3):

You can create yourself a module that listens for the index action on the *catalogsearch* modules' result-controller.

Then you check if the result is empty by inspecting the query model obtained from that module helper:

```
$query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
/* @var $query Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query */

$query->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

If you then want to trigger a redirect on any query, just overwrite the `redirect` data-member and by making the object unsaveable:

```
$query->setRedirect('/your/redirect/uri');
$query->setId(null);
$query->isDeleted(true);
```

Then the layout of the result won't render but instead the controller action will do the redirect for you. You can see that within the method `Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController::indexAction()` (`app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php`). Just look for a place that is easy to interact with by going through with a step-debugger like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). The underlying EAV model with implications on search is documented here as well: [Magento EAV System (Solving Magento)](http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-eav-system/).

See as well:

- [How to call a method before the method of requested controller is executed : magento](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4003450/367456)
- [Events and Observers: a Magento Tutorial](http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/)
- [Magento - to forward to different controller action from pre dispatch observer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11592948/367456)
- [Magento: How to Override Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17680604/367456)

Answer (score -3):

It is belong form magento ,,

you can check it form 2 side  
1- Go into Catalog Block product list in core file and check there product size and redirect .. where you want..

2- from frontend /design/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
if no item then redirect it by header('location:url');die;